# SPFx - Template for Angular 2

Tags: spfx, template, sharepoint-framework, typescript, angular2

I need to install an **Angular 2** template, but when I try the [GitHub templates](https://github.com/biserkacvetkovska/angular2-app) I have mistakes. Would you give me a quality template or tutorial  for Angular 2 with SPFx:

Errors:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've not looked at the code from the template that you've linked, but what is in your screenshot appears to be warnings and is simply the linter advising that there things to correct. Assuming that everything works as expected in the workbench when running `gulp serve`, it shouldn't take too long to correct the warnings that are in the screenshot you provided, after which you can then reuse the code you have as a template as required.

I'm not aware of an Angular2 template I'm afraid, but there is a Microsoft example with Angular2 [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/angular2-prototype).

Regarding a tutorial, I cannot find one for Angular 2, but Waldek Mastykarz has an article on Angular1 [here](https://blog.mastykarz.nl/building-sharepoint-framework-client-side-web-parts-angular/). Pretty much all of Mastykarz's stuff is gold in my eyes, especially with SPFx.